# Let $g$ be real valued and continuous on [0,1]. Show that if $f(z) = \int_0^1 g(t) (\cos zt) dt $ is 0 for all complex $z$ then $g$ is identically 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $g$ be real valued and continuous on [0,1]. Show that if the complex valued function $$f(z) := \int_0^1 g(t) (\cos zt) dt $$ is 0 for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $g$ is identically 0.

I managed to show that $f$ is an entire function by showing its continuity and then using Morera’s Theorem, but know not how to proceed with the assumption that $f$ is 0 on $\mathbb{C}$.

I thought that assuming $g$ were not 0 would allow me to locate a $z$ such that $f(z)\neq 0$ but I had no such luck. I would appreciate suggestions on what to do next.

Comment: Is $f$ bounded?

Comment: Not necessarily, without the assumption that $f$ is identically 0.